# R.string vs R.id in android

Tags: android

I have some code that says

MainActivity.java

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView av; //UI reference
    int textString = R.string.start;
    int backgroundColor = Color.DKGRAY;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // Create runnable for posting results to the UI thread
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    av.setText(textString);
    av.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    av = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.computation_status);
    Button actionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action1);
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    doWork();
    }
    });
    }
    //example of a computationally intensive action with UI updates
    private void doWork() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    textString=R.id.start;
    backgroundColor = Color.DKGRAY;
    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    computation(1);
    textString=R.id.first;

    backgroundColor = Color.BLUE;
    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    computation(2);
    textString=R.id.second;
    backgroundColor = Color.GREEN;
    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }
    });
    thread.start();
    }
    final static int SIZE=1000; //large enough to take some time
    double tmp;
    private void computation(int val) {
    for(int ii=0; ii<SIZE; ii++)
    for(int jj=0; jj<SIZE; jj++)
    tmp=val*Math.log(ii+1)/Math.log1p(jj+1);
    }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/computation_status"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="start textview" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+string/first" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/action1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that if that was R.id.start then there would have to be a textview in the xml file named start. What do I do if I have R.string.start? Because making a textview doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry reread it. res/val/strings.xml contains your strings. Look at the ones already in there and use those to make a similar one named start. Then use String start = context.getResources().getString(R.string.start); where R.string.start is an int reference to the string in your xml and context is whatever your context is.

Comment: Also, if you just want the int value of the resource just use int startId = R.string.start; But yea the string belongs in your res/values/strings.xml file

Answer (score 3):

`R.string.start` is actually a **reference** to a string named `start`, not the string itself.
So, it's an int.
`R.id` are the ids for the **views**

Comment: I'm getting the error: start cannot be resolved or is not a field message. If R.string.start is a reference, then whatever it is trying to reference isn't seeing each other. Do you know why. I added code to my original post.

Comment: `start` should be a string in your `values/strings.xml` (or however you named it). If you want to reference a TextView named `start`, since a TextView is a View, use the `R.id.start` integer (you have to use `findViewById()`)

Comment: @user3912157 Frank's anser/comment mixed with my comment should get you where you need to go. Or at least get you started :P